# Finding a probability of variable's 1st and/or 2nd digit being 3 from uniform distrb.

Tags: probability

Problem 1:

A random variable X is uniform [0,1]. Find the probability that X's 2nd digit is 3.

As far as I understood, I need to find the probability of interval 0.03 - 0.04? And also all intervals that have 3 in 2nd digit? Like:

0.03 - 0.04
0.13 - 0.14
0.23 - 0.24
0.33 - 0.34
0.43 - 0.44
0.53 - 0.64
0.63 - 0.64
0.73 - 0.74
0.83 - 0.84
0.93 - 0.94

And then add the probability of each interval? Could someone help me, please?

Problem 2:

A random variable X is uniform [0,3]. Find the probability that X's first and/or second digit is 2.

I actually don't know how to tackle this problem. Could somebody point out what should I do with this?. Somehow ended up being in class with calculus. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: (1) If I understand the question correctly, you are using continuous uniform distributions. Then each digit has 1 chance in 10 of being a 3. (2) First digit has 1 chance in 3 of being a 2, 2nd digit 1 chance in 10 of being a 2. Avoiding both has probability $(2/3)(9/10).$ Contrary event $1-(2/3)(9/10).$ Think about it. Leave a comment if you think I'm wrong and maybe someone will answer.

Comment: Re: (1) you can indeed add all the segments you listed.  They will sum to length 0.1 and you will get the same answer 1/10 as @BruceET indicated.